# jQuery dropdown menu selected

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have this dropdown menu and on change, the `window.location.href` changes, but how would i go about making the selected value selected when the page changes?

```
<div class="iPhoneNav">
    <select class="iPhoneDropdown">
            <option value="/">Home</option>
            <option value="/services">Services</option>
            <option value="/about-us">About Us</option>
            <option value="/gallery">Gallery</option>
            <option value="/testimonials">Testimonials</option>
            <option value="/tours">Tours</option>
            <option value="/contact-us">Contact Us</option>
            <option></option>
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($){

                    $(function(){
                            $('select').change(function(index){
                                    window.location.href = $(this).val();
                            });

                    });

            })(jQuery);     
    </script>
```

Comment: @AndyRay I read derpdown, amused and confused me lol. On a more serious note, you may be interested in `location.pathname`.

Comment: I think you need to wrap the whole thing in a document.ready function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `select` like this example, just try to set the value using the pathname:

```
$(function(){
    $('.iPhoneDropdown').val(location.pathname);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store some value or id of the selected option in body or with some elements with "data ". Give unique ids to your option tags.After selecting option store the selected option "id" with data.

Try this,

```
<div class="iPhoneNav">
<select class="iPhoneDropdown">
        <option id="1" value="/">Home</option>
        <option id="2" value="/services">Services</option>
        <option id="3" value="/about-us">About Us</option>
        <option id="4" value="/gallery">Gallery</option>
        <option id="5" value="/testimonials">Testimonials</option>
        <option id="6" value="/tours">Tours</option>
        <option id="7" value="/contact-us">Contact Us</option>
        <option></option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){

                $(function(){

                        if($('body').data('selected_opt') != "" || $('body').data('selected') != 'undefined') {
                            var op_id = $('body').data('selected_opt');
                            $('select').find('option[id="' + op_id + '"]').attr('selected', true);    //you can also use prop instead of attr
                        }
                        $('select').change(function(index){
                            $('body').data('selected_opt', $(this).attr('id'));
                            window.location.href = $(this).val();
                        });

                });

        })(jQuery);     
</script>
```